# warnings while installing ruby Devkit on windows 7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, devkit

I am trying install devkit on windows 7 but getting below error while issuing command
ruby dk.rb install.

**[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3'**

So i tried >ruby dk.rb install --force but now i am getting this error,

**[WARN] Updating (with backup) existing gem override for 'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1
.9.3'
[WARN] Updating (with backup) DevKit helper library for 'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1
.9.3'**

I have installed ruby using rails installer.
This is the content in my config.yml file,

```
# This configuration file contains the absolute path locations of all
# installed Rubies to be enhanced to work with the DevKit. This config
# file is generated by the 'ruby dk.rb init' step and may be modified
# before running the 'ruby dk.rb install' step. To include any installed
# Rubies that were not automagically discovered, simply add a line below
# the triple hyphens with the absolute path to the Ruby root directory.
#
# Example:
#
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
#
---

- C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Is just a warning, ignore it, don't `--force` it, use Ruby and live long and prosper.